# table couldn't be found in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I created a db in mysql phpmyadmin.i have canvas as a db and students as a table. i Created an ORM using Sequelize it keeps saying the table not found i am using postman to post to the table it should give me response of the email and message. this is postman error that am getting `errorSequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'canvas.students' doesn't exist` Thanks.

this is my db.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = {}
const sequelize = new Sequelize('canvas', 'root', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8889,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    operatorAliases: false,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 3000,
        idle: 10000
    }
})
db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Squelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db;
```

this is mymodel

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../database/db.js')

module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
    'student', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        created: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    }

)
```

Comment: refer to this answer [sequelize import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970819/6638515) in short if your model is in the separate file use the import method available on sequelize instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs with sequelize couldn't create table in mysql workbench after starting the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957159/nodejs-with-sequelize-couldnt-create-table-in-mysql-workbench-after-starting-th)

Comment: thanks that worked.

Comment: I'm glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = db.sequelize.define(
'student', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    created: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false


  }

)
```

This line - **'student', {** in your model definition **student** is the table name not **students** hence the error - **Table 'canvas.students' doesn't exist**